# What the purple/ gold symbol over 2 character in the new HotS loading screen?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

What do these symbols mean?? Does it mean they are in a group?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a new feature added in the [Dec 15, 2015 patch](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/19981657/heroes-of-the-storm-patch-notes-december-15-2015-12-15-2015#User_Interface) to help identify which players are grouped together in a party.

> **Party Indicator Icons**
>
> New Loading Screen icons have been added to indicate which players queued together as a part:
>
> - Players in the same party will appear next to each other on loading screens.
> - Parties will be separated by icon color so that it is easier to see how many parties there are, and how many players are in each.